# Dropdown bootstrap no funciona en AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bootstrap-4, electron

Buen día a todos. Antes que nada gracias por tomarse el tiempo de revisar mi problema.

Estoy trabajando un programita simple para Windows a través de ELECTRON , usando el framework de ANGULARJS. y BOOTSTRAP 4.1 para la UI. para mi sorpresa me encontré al realizar un menú desplegable que el  `dropdown` no funciona... Pero no funciona de verdad... o al menos eso he resuelto luego de intentar con distintas versiones de JQUERY, POPPER.JS y BOOTSTRAP.js , BOOTSTRAP.MIN.JS, bootstrap.bundle.js.

Les dejo el código, verán que en este editor que tiene stackoverflow funciona. Sin embargo tengo exactamente lo mismo en el mismo orden pero estoy trabajando en ELECTRON lo cual no debería de ser un problema al ser solo un transpilador. gracias nuevamente.

El error que recibo es `util.js:56 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="dropdown text-right">
  <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Probablemente no se está cargando _jQuery_ y supongo que el error lo marca cuando se trata de [extender alguna funcionalidad](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.fn.extend/). ¿En qué momento cargas `utils.js`?

Comment: Hola , gracias por respondes. Utils.js es un archivo de bootstrap.js. por lo tanto este lo carga indirectamente el bootstrap. Pero tienes razón el problema es con los tiempos de ejecucion , al parecer no carga, o no termina de cargar el JQUERY. Encontré esta solución. De esta manera si me funciona el dropdown. `<script type="text/javascript" src="./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" onload="window.$ = window.jQuery = module.exports;"></script>` Pero quisiera una forma mas amigable de hacer esto desde el lado del controlador angularJS